# Google Analytics API: Can I view time and location of every visit?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am writing a PHP script to access Google Analytics data using API.
I need to get the following report:
Within given time range for every visitor coming from paid search I need to know time of the visit and location (City) the visitor came from.

Is it possible to construct such a query? What dimensions/metrics/filters will look like?
Example would be great!

Comment: you can easily make your query here at http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/
About the dimension/metric combination possibilities check https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets

Answer (score 0):

No. Google Analytics does not show data for exact minutes (hour of the day is the smallest unit of time) and it does not report single visits/user sessions - GA only reports aggregated data. You can have aggregated values for CPC visits from a given City for a given hour of the day but that's the closest it gets.